# ACRA is crashing

Tags: android, acra

I am using ACRA for crash reporting, but all of a sudden it is causing me some problems. My application won't start, I get a crash report notification, but tapping on it does nothing. Opening logcat, I can see the following entries:

```
 11-20 19:25:53.093: E/ACRA(16233): ACRA caught a RuntimeException exception for com.skipmorrow.phca. Building report.
 11-20 19:25:53.763: D/ApplicationPolicy(716): isStatusBarNotificationAllowed: packageName = com.skipmorrow.phca
 11-20 19:25:53.763: E/ACRA(16233): com.skipmorrow.phca fatal error : Unable to create application com.skipmorrow.phca.ACRA: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
 11-20 19:25:53.763: E/ACRA(16233): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.skipmorrow.phca.ACRA: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
 11-20 19:25:53.763: E/ACRA(16233):     at com.skipmorrow.phca.ACRA.onCreate(ACRA.java:89)
```

Not much to go on, but it looks like ACRA itself is having problems.

Here is my ACRA implementation class:

```
 package com.skipmorrow.phca;

 import org.acra.annotation.*;
 import org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode;

 import android.app.Application;

 @ReportsCrashes(
 formKey = "dFdSMXh...E6MQ",
 mode = ReportingInteractionMode.NOTIFICATION,
 resNotifTickerText = R.string.crash_notif_ticker_text,
 resNotifTitle = R.string.crash_notif_title,
 resNotifText = R.string.crash_notif_text,
 resNotifIcon = android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error, // optional. default is a warning sign
 resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text,
 resDialogIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, //optional. default is a warning sign
 resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title, // optional. default is your application name
 resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.crash_dialog_comment_prompt, // optional. when defined, adds a user text field input with this text resource as a label
 resDialogOkToast = R.string.crash_dialog_ok_toast, // optional. displays a Toast message when the user accepts to send a report.
 logcatArguments = {
        "-t"
        ,"2000"
        ,"-v"
        ,"time"
        ,"PHCA_ActionCommand:D"
        ,"ActionParameterEditTextActivity:D"
        ,"ActionParameterSeekbarActivity:D"
        ,"PHCA_C2DMReceiver:D"
        ,"PHCA_CommonActivity:D"
        ,"PHCA_ConfigurationActionCommandChooser:D"
        ,"PHCA_ConfigurationAddNewAction:D"
        ,"PHCA_ConfigurationAddNewPage:D"
        ,"PHCA_ConfigurationAddNewPagelink:D"
        ,"PHCA_ConfigurationAddNewPageStatus:D"
        ,"PHCA_ConfigurationEditActionCommand:D"
        ,"PHCA_ConfigurationEditPageRefreshUpdateActivity:D"
        ,"PHCA_ConfigurationEditVariable:D"
        ,"PHCA_ConfigurationEditVariableValueSetting:D"
        ,"PHCA_ConfigurationLandingPage:D"
        ,"PHCA_ConfigurationPageChooserActivity:D"
        ,"PHCA_ConfigurationPageObjectChooserActivity:D"
        ,"PHCA_ConfigurationRefreshUpdateChooserActivity:D"
        ,"PHCA_DBAdapter:D"
        ,"PHCA_DragListener:D"
        ,"PHCA_DragNDropAdapter:D"
        ,"PHCA_DragNDropListView:D"
        ,"PHCA_DropListener:D"
        ,"PHCA_EditC2dmSettingsActivity:D"
        ,"PHCA_EditGlobalPrefsActivity:D"
        ,"PHCA_EnterFilenameForBackup:D"
        ,"PHCA_EnterPinActivity:D"
        ,"PHCA_EnterPinDialog:D"
        ,"PHCA_HttpNetworking:D"
        ,"PHCA_ListLabels:D"
        ,"PHCA_MyListArrayAdapter:D"
        ,"PHCA_Page:D"
        ,"PHCA_PageAction:D"
        ,"PHCA_PageChooserDialog:D"
        ,"PHCA_PageImageActivity:D"
        ,"PHCA_PageLink:D"
        ,"PHCA_PageListActivity:D"
        ,"PHCA_PageRefreshUpdate:D"
        ,"PHCA_PageStatus:D"
        ,"PHCA_PhcaActivity:D"
        ,"PHCA_PhcaAppWidgetConfigurator:D"
        ,"PHCA_PhcaAppWidgetProvider:D"
        ,"PHCA_PhcaMenu:D"
        ,"PHCA_PhcaPrefs:D"
        ,"PHCA_PhcaUtils:D"
        ,"PHCA_RemoveListener:D"
        ,"PHCA_SocketServerNetworking:D"
        ,"PHCA_Variable:D"
        ,"PHCA_VariableChooser:D"
        ,"PHCA_VariableSetting:D"
        ,"PHCA_VariableValueSettingChooser:D"
        ,"PHCA_VisiblePhcaPageObject:D"
        ,"PHCA_WidgetDialogResponseActivity:D"
        ,"PHCA_XmlFileChooser:D"
        ,"PHCA_XmlNodeCounter:D"
        ,"PHCA_XmlParser:D"
        ,"*:S"
        }
 )

 public class ACRA extends Application {
    @Override
     public void onCreate() {
         // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        org.acra.ACRA.init(this); // <<<<====== LINE 89
         super.onCreate();
     }  
 }
```

One other clue (I think) is the fact that in my ACRA class, in the onCreate, I have to call init with the fully qualified

```
org.acra.ACRA.init(this)
```

**EDIT** I can't believe I left this out the first time. THIS IS LINE 89 in com.skipmorrow.phca.ACRA

In other projects where I have used ACRA, I didn't have to do that (and, in fact, the instructions call init() with just ACRA.init(this). Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Use ACRA to catch ACRA crashes... Inception! ;)

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com +1 Like! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash is not within ACRA.

It is at line 89 of this class 
  com.skipmorrow.phca.ACRA.onCreate(ACRA.java:89)

This is NOT an ACRA class. All ACRA classes are in the package org.acra. Not sure where com.skipmorrow.phca.ACRA comes from, but you need to look there.

Comment: I edited my OP. Line 89 is the call to init(). I have no idea why it would crash on that line.

Comment: Crash was caused by my inadvertent importing and mishandling of an old acra shared preference.

Comment: @MrGibbage can you provide more detail on this mishandling, so others may benefit?